# Save redirect URL on auth guard rejection in Angular 4

Tags: angular, routes

I have a protected route `/protected-route`. The `authentication-guard.service.ts` file dictates that a user must be thrown to `/login` if a valid session is not found:

```
/* --- Angular --- */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

/* --- Services --- */
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedRouteGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private 
router: Router, private routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot) { }

  canActivate() {

    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) { return true; } else {

      console.log(this.routerStateSnapshot.url);

      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

      return false;

    }

  }

}
```

I would like to save the attempted route, i.e. `/protected-route` to be able to redirect the user after successful login. I am unable to get the route information before the user gets thrown to `/login`. `router.url` and `activatedRoute.snapshot.url` both return empty values.

Comment: Are you implementing `CanActivate` interface? If yes, inside the `canActivate` method you have the `state` (`RouteStateSnapshot`).. save the `state.url` somewhere and use it after user authenticates..

Comment: Says no provider for RouterStateSnapshot. Updating the question to include the file.

Comment: Your method is implementing the `canActivate` method wrongly..

Comment: how did you get it to work? I'm facing exactly the same issues as you - first the blank values and also the "no provider" errors? - Edit: Nevermind - I got it too. For anyone who comes here with the same issue - checkout https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: Yo people ya better, somebody put some working answer here so facing the same issue people could find it useful ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your AuthenticatedRouteGuardService

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
}
```